# NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID after time change. Should i change azure time zone for the site?

Tags: azure

After time change my site is unaccessible for all my customer with almost all browsers. 
Should i change the timezone in Azure?

Comment: What do you mean after time change? What did you change?

Answer (score 0):

You probably changed the time of a VM right? You have to change that to the correct time. The validity of a certificate depends on clock skew tolerances. If you want to change the timezone or locale, do that, but not the server time.